# Search column in one Excel workbook to paste Adjacent Cell's Value into active VBA script

Tags: vba, excel

I have Workbook1 and Workbook2 and need to search column A in Workbook1 for specific string value and then copy adjacent cell that is in column B of Workbook1 to the macro being run where I need to insert the value in the following formula in VBA script: =(ROUNDUP((F2+40)/[VALUE],0))*[VALUE]. The [VALUE] = the value taken from the adjacent cell in column B from Workbook1. Workbook2 is where the macro is running on.

I am being rushed at the moment and if this is not clear enough. I will come back and clarify as needed.

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Sorry about that. When I asked this question I was being pressured to make a meeting but wanted to see if anyone could understand what I was after. After looking into this I finally came up with a better way to accomplish this and will share it below

[ Range("H2").Select
        ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-2], 'V:\Diecutter\[fundraisingdies.xlsx]Sheet1'!R2C[-7]:R100C[-6], 2, FALSE)" ]

Answer (score 0):

```
VALUE = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(theString, Workbooks("Workbook1").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A:B"), 2)
```